# Django CSRF verification failed after setting SSL with Certbot

Tags: django, nginx, ssl

I'm currently working on a Django project that utilizes Docker, and I recently set up an SSL certificate using a containerized version of [Certbot](https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/certbot) in order to secure my Django app through HTTPS. However, after implementing the SSL certificate and updating my nginx configuration, I began to experience the 'CSRF verification failed' error, which was not an issue before the setup. Previously, I was able to log into my Django app when it was using HTTP. What could be the cause of this problem?

My Django setting.

```
# settings.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

if DEBUG:
    CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
else:
    CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
    CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
        'https://example.ph',
    ]
```

My previous nginx configuration.

```
upstream api {
    server sinag_app:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }
}
```

My new nginx configuration with SSL certificate.

```
upstream api {
    server sinag_app:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ${DOMAIN};

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /vol/www;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ${DOMAIN};

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/${DOMAIN}/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/${DOMAIN}/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    ssl_dhparam /vol/proxy/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```